# Where to download Subsonic 2.2 Sourcecode without svn client?

Tags: svn, subsonic, tortoisesvn

Checkout with svn does not work in my environment. Im looking for the sourcecode of Subsonic 2.2 as zip file for example..

Comment: Based on the fact that you got it working with an HTTP tunnelling client, I'm assuming that this is because your corporate firewall blocks the extra HTTP (OPTIONS, REPORT, PROPGET, etc.) verbs used by SVN.

There wasn't enough information in your question (the exact error message would have been a good start, for example) for anyone else to figure this out.

Comment: Youre right.. i will write more detailed questions in the future..
I tried some proxy parameters in svn the server ini file.. but no success. So.. i used the tunnel..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using the HTTP Tunnel Client (http://www.http-tunnel.com) and setting the tortoise/svn proxy to 127.0.0.1:1080
Slow, but it works.